# Nested observable filtering

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have an `Observable` that has list of items. Each item has a `selected$` (boolean) observable. I need to filter out items, that have non-truth values.

Here is my solution, it feels a bit cumbersome, but it does the job. Is there a better solution?

```
interface ICarrier {
  readonly id: number;
  readonly selected$: Observable<boolean>;
}

const allCarriers$ = of<readonly ICarrier[]>([]); // Placeholder value!
const selectedCarriers$ = allCarriers$.pipe(
  switchMap(carriers => {
    return combineLatest(carriers.map(carrier => carrier.selected$.pipe(
      map(selected => selected ? carrier : null),
    ))).pipe(
      // Prevent multiple filtering when multiple values changes at once.
      debounceTime(0),
      // filter out null values
      map(carriers => carriers.filter((carrier): carrier is ICarreir => !!carrier)),
    );
  }),
);
```

Comment: If your pipeline looks more complex than usual, it's because an Observable of an array of objects which each contain an observable property is more complex than usual. Your solution might be warranted, but I'd be looking to simplify so you weren't dealing with objects containing observable properties.

Comment: I agree. I'd try to remove the Observable from the interface. But without more information, it may be difficult to suggest alternatives. Maybe stick with a simple property and use a more general selected Observable that emits the id of the selected carrier?

Comment: I used `selected$` as an easy example. I practice I use `motive$` that depends on 2 other external observables...